# Multiple rows in tableview reacts to one action intended for the subview of one row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

The problem I'm facing is that subviews of two rows are reacting to an action intended for the subview of just one row.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1zEO.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avbAg.png)

The images that I posted above are the results of only pressing the star subview button in the row of "Acetate"

The following is my code:

First, for the subclass of `UIView` that makes the button fill up on touch.

```
import UIKit

class StarButton: UIView {

var order : Int = 0

override init (frame : CGRect)
{
    super.init(frame : frame)
    initStar()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initStar()
}

func initStar(){

    let filledStarImage = UIImage(named: "filledStar")
    let emptyStarImage = UIImage(named: "emptyStar")

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 2, y: 2, width: 33, height: 33))

    button.userInteractionEnabled = true
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(StarButton.fillingStar(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    let comparator = favoritesList.stringForKey("\(order)")

    if (comparator != nil){
        button.selected = true
    }

    button.setImage(emptyStarImage, forState: .Normal)
    button.setImage(filledStarImage, forState: .Selected)

    addSubview(button)
}


func fillingStar(sender: UIButton){
    if (sender.selected) == false{
        favoritesList.setObject(ChemQuizCollection.wordListObject.quizList[order], forKey: "\(order)")
        sender.selected = !sender.selected
        favoritesList.synchronize()
    } else{
        favoritesList.removeObjectForKey("\(order)")
        sender.selected = !sender.selected
        favoritesList.synchronize()
    }


}
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
    for view in subviews
    {
        view.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    }
}

override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
{
    return true
}


}
```

Secondly, for the `UITableViewController`

```
class WordListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 0...25{
        favoritesList.setObject(nil, forKey: "\(i)")
    }
    favoritesList.synchronize()


    //setting the wordList of wordListObject


    ChemQuizCollection.wordListObject.quizList.sortInPlace()

    ChemQuizCollection.formulaImages.sortInPlace()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 30

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 25
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("WordListTableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WordListTableViewCell

        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.starButtonView.order = row

        cell.formulaLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
        cell.formulaLabel.text = ChemQuizCollection.wordListObject.quizList[row]
        cell.formulaImage.image = UIImage(named: ChemQuizCollection.formulaImages[row])

        return cell
    }
```

I just pasted a bulk of my code, so that it would make more sense. Please tell me if you want some parts to be more explained, or if the code should be trimmed more to show the essential parts.

Thank you all for your help in advance. Stackoverflow is such a wonderful community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you cell is beeing reused in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. So, you have to update your `StarButton` state. You can do something like that:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("WordListTableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WordListTableViewCell


// Here, you check if favoritesList contains the current item
// If yes, you set the button to enabled = true.
// If no, you set the button to enable = false


        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem I have now is how I am to access the subview of the StarButton, which is the actual UIButton. Since StarButton is a subclass of UIView that has a UIButton subview (which is the star icon in my table), I need to able to access that UIButton subview, but I can't find out how.
Trying:
for subview in cell.starButtonView.subviews{
   subview.selected = true
}
throws an error saying UIView doesn't have member "selected"

Comment: Also, I don't get why the button's state should be updated depending on favoritesList's current item. The button fills or empties depending on the user's touch. It changes state only when the user touches it.
favoritesList exists so that when the user touches the button, the item associated to that row gets saved locally to the device.